# Is it possible to build UWP app in Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, windows-10, uwp

Is it possible to build the UWP app in the Mac platform? Like I have Mac PC and the new Visual Studio Code can use to write codes, but is it possible to install the Emulators and SDK for Windows 10 / UWP? I want to build apps for Windows platform.

Comment: If you want to build UWP apps it's really best to have a local test system (i.e. Windows 10). It's the most efficient way to test and debug an UWP app, even if you don't plan on targeting PCs. And that's why the dev tools are available for Windows only (you need Windows 7/8/8.1 for building, Windows 10 for building and running).

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately currently there is no option to use UWP dev tools on the MAC even with Visual Studio Code. The same is for Linux.