# Cordova Build Windows 10 App on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cordova, jenkins, msbuild

Hi there I hope this question wasn't answered anywhere else on SO, but 4h spent on research is enough for today. 
My simple question is, if it's possible to build a **Windows10 App** with **cordova** on **Mac OS X** (10.12). Why I want to do such kind of thingy is that I just set up jenkins for some of our projects and we are working with Xamarin, Cordava and native ones, I wanted to configure jenkins for each of them to automate iOS, Android and Windows builds. Everything is working so far, but when I try to build windows cordova app it fails with the following message:

```
cordova build windows --release
Error: spawn ENOTDIR
```

I watched the logs and recognized at some point cordova is trying to find *MsBuildToolsPath* in Registry with:

```
reg query ...
```

which is acceptable not working on Mac OS. So I tried to build with *msbuild* directly:

```
msbuild /p:Platform=AnyCPU /p:Configuration=Release CordovaApp.sln
```

Which throws following error:

> MSB4226: The imported project
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/JavaScript/Microsoft.VisualStudio.WJProject.Default.props"
>   was not found. Also, tried to find
>   "Microsoft/VisualStudio/v15.0/JavaScript/Microsoft.VisualStudio.WJProject.Default.props"
>   in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32) -
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/" . These search
>   paths are defined in
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/MSBuild.dll.config".
>   Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that
>   the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.

I followed the path and the files cordova is looking for are not existent, but I found nothing on how to install the Javascript Tools on Mac OS without re/installing Visual Studio.

I am not into cordova so excuse me if this question is not worth wasting your time, but if anybody could help me to get this last platform build succeeding with Jenkins I would really appreciate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39243485/is-it-possible-to-build-uwp-app-in-mac

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Windows 10 UWP apps the answer is **no**. See the question also linked in the comments and the documentation on Visual Studio 2017 for Mac Platform [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-mac):

> Visual Studio for Mac does not support Windows client projects like
>   Windows Forms, WPF, or UWP.

---

Possible solutions:

- [Set up your Mac with Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/setting-up-your-mac-with-windows-10): Microsoft suggests using Bootcamp, Parallels or a virtual machine with VMware or VirtualBox to run Windows 10 and be able to develop UWP apps on you Mac.
- Use a build service: Depending on your requirements, you may consider using a build service. Most popular service might be https://build.phonegap.com/. It [does support building UWP apps](https://phonegap.com/blog/2016/04/25/windows-10-and-phonegap-cli-6_1-now-on-build/). You can see their plans [here](https://build.phonegap.com/#plans).

Comment: Thank you very much for this information I clearly was not seeing this in the documentation.